# Android shape background

Tags: android, background, shapes

Is it possible to draw a shape in xml, and use a png as the background to that shape? I already have the shape (it's a square with rounded corners), and i would like to put a background to that square.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Yes you can use any shape file as background for any view. This sample create rounded background with white color and black border around the shape.

Sample :

rounded_corner.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="@color/color_grey" />

    <solid android:color="@color/color_white" />

</shape>
```

u can use this as,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: instead of white color can we place any drawable i.e an image?

Comment: No you can not add any drawable in shape xml it only takes color.

Comment: OP wants .png image to be in background.

Comment: Yeah, finally i "cheated", because i have drawn the shape in Photoshop and added the background manually,but i would still like an idea for this.Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can you describe in brief. I am unable to understand what are you trying to archive.

Comment: @DrupDesai OP knows how to make a shape in xml, but the question is specifically about a shape with a png background, instead of a color

Comment: Can a shape's background be a reference? like -> android:color="?btn_background"

Answer (score 1):

//try this way this will help you

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/yourdrawable />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In my blank `Xamarin.Android` project, there's no folder called `drawable` under `Resources`. If i put the shape inside the `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder, then i can access it and use it properly inside the emulator, but the app crashes on a real divice with the following error : `Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class`. Any idea on why this might be happening? Read my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583311/xamarin-android-crashes-when-trying-to-load-style-from-resource)