# Xamarin.Android Crashes When Trying To Load Style From Resource

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

Another day with Xamarin and another issue!

So, blank `Xamarin.Android` project. Created a custom style/shape in the `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder under resources because it's not accessible if i create it elsewhere or even in another new sub-folder. Even there's no `drawable` folder anywhere in the solution(which is very puzzling for me.)

Anyways, here's how it looks :

**myshape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
  <size android:height="10dp" android:width="10dp"/>
  <corners android:radius="130dp" />
</shape>
```

Then i set it as a `background` of a `LinearLayout` as follows :

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="match_parent"
               android:background="@mipmap/myshape"/>
```

It shows perfectly within the designer. Even within the emulator, it works great in both debug and release mode.

Thr problem arises when i try to debug it in a physical device(**Samsung Galaxy J2**). It runs Android 5.1(API Level 22) (*Note that my project's minimum requirement is API level 21*). So, when i try to debug the app through the device, i get the following error :

> Java.Lang.Exception: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class

Error is throws in the following line in `MainActivity.cs`'s `OnCreate()` method :

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
```

However, if i set the background as `ic_launcher` which appears to be a logo, but is stored as an `.xml` file in `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder, it works perfectly. The `ic_launcher.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
 <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

So, i am a bit confused as how do i set a shape as a background then? I have gone through other SO posts but almost all of them seem to have the `drawable` folder which is missing in my case. Even in a new project, the folder is missing. You can simply reproduce it by creating a blank `Xamarin.Android` project.

So, any ideas on why it may be crashing on on a physical device?

Comment: You may have a `Resources` folder, if yes create a `drawable` folder inside `Resources` and try moving your shape to this folder. After that try `Build->Clean Solution` and then `Build->Rebuild Solution`.

Comment: @sunilsunny Tried it already, but this way it can't even access the shape at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...have the drawable folder which is missing in my case.

Just create a `drawable` folder within your `Resources` folder.

Note: Do this via the IDE's solution/project explorer, not the file-system.

There are a number of Resources folders and Xamarin templates do not create all of them by default.

Note: They actually become `res/xxxx` within the Android APK file structure.

re: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

[image]

Comment: Tried it already, but this way it can't even access the shape at all.

Comment: Ok, so it seems to work inside the emulator. However, i wonder  why, in design view, it doesn;t show anything.

Comment: Yeah, now it works perfectly on the device as well! But one question. I am not able to see the style/shape in designer anymore. If this keeps going on, how am i able to even develop the UI at all?

Comment: @zackraiyan The Xamarin.Android design view is not *always* the greatest thing  and there are times you have to close the layout file and re-open it or even restart Visual Studio to get it working again...  (Note: personally I use Android Studio for its hard core layout tools and once I am happy drag/drop the "res" subfolders into VS IDE Resources folder (there is at least one 3rd-party VSIX extension that does this automatically so you can toggle between Android Studio and Visual Studio to help in this process, but I just drag/drop....)

Comment: Can you give me the link to the extension?

Comment: @zackraiyan I do not use it and can not remember the name, search the Visual Studio add-in store for it/them....

Comment: No problem. Thanks again mate.

Comment: By the way, can you give me a little guidance on custom controls in Xamarin.Android? Please do take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55564952/xamarin-android-creating-and-using-custom-controls?noredirect=1#comment97829895_55564952)